# Powershell is always using wrong Java

Tags: java, powershell

As far as i know you can use every Java version when you are just in the right directory.
Lets say i have on my PC Java 8 and Java 15. They are both located in `C:\Program Files\java`.
So when i go in `C:\Program Files\java\jre1.8.0_291\bin` and run in cmd `java.exe -version` i get the version 1.8 .
The same goes with Powershell.

But here comes the problem. When i go to `C:\Program Files\java\jdk-15.0.1\bin` i get in cmd the version 1.15, but in Powershell i still get 1.8.
I think that Powershell always refers to the standard JRE installed.

Comment: What does `Get-Command java.exe` resolve to (when you're inside the `jdk-15*` bin folder)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `.\` before the command.

`java.exe` will run the first java in your PATH.
`.\java.exe` will run the java.exe in your current directory.

Comment: Thaks for the Answer.  
Didnt know that PS is so close to the Linux terminal.

Answer (score 1):

you need .\ before the command to run the one in your current directory

personally, I use the below to switch versions, its a script that sets the JAVA home. This can be used when in any java dirs to use different versions

```
@echo off
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16
set Path=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%Path%
echo Java 16 activated.
```

link to method I used below
https://www.happycoders.eu/java/how-to-switch-multiple-java-versions-windows/

Comment: Thanks for the script.
I will use it in the future.